# Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, aar

To package all dependencies of my Library into .aar file, I have used https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android and I am able to see all dependencies in libs folder of .aar file (checked by extracting it). But when I used resulting .aar file in sample project, I am getting below build error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
```

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform MyMobileSDK-debug-.aar (:MyMobileSDK-debug:) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /home/abhishek.kumar/AndroidStudioProjects/sdk-api-android/app/libs/MyMobileSDK-debug.aar.
> > duplicate entry: META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the third party open source library behind my issue: com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1

I have used 'transitive = false' to resolve issue.

embed ("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1") {
transitive = false
}

Thanks Jeroen Mols for the wonderful blog (https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2020/11/11/library-dependencies/)